# certificate for push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to create a certificate for push notification.
Made the process of generating the certificate on my Mac
In the key generation when I send my certificate for the site does not generate the certificate is loading and not ends.

that will be done some bad process.

thanks for the help.

Comment: If I read this right, you uploaded the certificate request generated on your mac, but on the website it doesn't ever say the push certificate is complete?  If so, just refresh the site and it should have the push certificate you need - you can download that, import it into your keychain and then export to upload to a push provider.

Comment: I followed tutorial from this [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960). It has php code which I used it to run it on my mac to test the code as well.

Comment: Solved my problem, i used safari. 
Problem in Chrome. 

Tanks...